# vbscript regex to handle word before OR after another word using a negative look ahead

Tags: regex, vbscript, conditional-statements, regex-lookarounds

I have the pattern below in a vbscript to turn my lights on/off.  It captures the case `"turn on the third bedroom light."`  However, is there an elegant way to also capture the case `"turn on the light in the third bedroom"` using an all-in-one pattern?

I know I can separate out the `(light|lite)` case in a separate pattern and use conditional logic, but I was looking for an all in one elegant pattern as I'm still learning regex.

Keep in mind that whatever pattern must also exclude the case `"third bedroom closet"` as shown in the pattern below.  Also note that vbscript doesn't support negative look behind (I think).

```
oRegExp.Pattern = "(third).(bedroom (?!closet)).*(light|lite)"
if oRegExp.Test(sVoice) then gProcessLight home.ThirdBedroom.Light,vPropValue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use alternatives for this:

```
(third bedroom (light|lite)|(light|lite).*third bedroom (?!closet))
```

Comment: Thanks!  I like your solution.  However, if I also wanted "turn on the third bedroom **overhead** light" to match or "turn on the third bedroom **desk** lamp" to match, I'm guessing I have to use this ugly looking expression:  ((third).(bedroom(?! closet)).*(light|lite|lamp))|((light|lite|lamp).*(third).(bedroom(?! closet)))

Comment: Maybe you should rethink your capturing pattern: Capture each word, see if that word is something meaningfull and combine all meaningfull words to the most likely command. Measuring the distance between certain words can improve the algorithm. And later on you can combine or exclude with connector words like `AND`, `NOT`, `EXCEPT` etc.: `turn off all lights except the hallway`.